# Compact one-to-one image of $[0,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact metrizable one-to-one continuous image of $[0,\infty)$.

If $X$ is locally connected, then I know $X$ must be the circle $S^1$ or the $P$ shape.

But does it have to be locally connected?

You do not have to post a proof if you can find a reference instead!

Thanks.

Comment: Similarly, I think the only compact (continuous, obviously!) images of $\Bbb R$ must be either $8$, $\theta$, or $0\!\!-\!\!0$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger That is certainly true among locally connected spaces.

Comment: Oh, right… So the Warsaw circle answers your question? (In addition to the 6 figure)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger oh, right.  Okay, I think this answers my question!

Answer (score 4):

Warsaw circle.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is still "shape theoretically" a circle, right? Not I that I know what Borsuk's shape theory is, really. +1

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @AreaMan Wikipedia says yes.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you insist on continuous, you can draw the letter b. (Do you consider it to be a circle? It does have the homotopy type of the circle.)

Comment: Same as P and 6

Comment: Ok, right.  I know the circle and your shape are the only compact one-to-one metrizable images which are locally connected.  Now what if local connectedness is dropped?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can biject $[0,\infty)$ with $[0,1]$

Comment: $f(x)=tan^{-1}x$

Comment: Sorry I was not precise enough in my question.  Please see edit

Comment: @u8y7541:  that is a start, but you still have to deal with the fact that the right end of the original interval is open and the right end of $[0,1]$ is closed.  That cannot be done continuously but the original question did not specify that.